# How to pass a list of files as a second argument in a Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a command-line program that I need to run on Windows. It takes 2 arguments:
argument1 is the name of the final file
argument 2 is a space separated list of files that will be merged into 1 files, which is named by argument 1.

I have a directory that contains several directories with .mp3 files in them. I need to have all those files listed as the 2nd argument to that command line program.

I tried several things, but none seem to be working.

How do I do this under Windows 7?

Thank you!

Comment: How would we know why your secret stuff ain't working. Andyour program seems to take many arguements.

Comment: There is nothing secret about it. Just wanted to make things more generic... Ok, if that helps, I can clarify... I am using mp3Wrap (http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/) to combine a bunch of MP3s into 1 MP3. If you can help with that, it would be great. How would I do this on Windows? (Here is the link to the man page for that program which shows the arguments: http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/man.html)
Thanks!

Comment: `"C:\Path to\mp3wrap" "C:\My Music\MyMP3.mp3" "C:\Path to my other MP3s\File1.mp3" "C:\Path to my other MP3s\File2.mp3"  "C:\Path to my other MP3s\File3.mp3"` Just depending on where you are in directory structure and where the files are and where you want them(and if mp3wrap is in the path), the paths above may be optional. Note: paths with spaces are enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Your program takes n arguments, 3 possible switch ones then Outputfile and as many input files as you have. We on the command line don't care what MP3Wrap thinks of the parameters. To it it may be two. We delimit parameters with spaces. If you had 4 input files you have 5 to 8 arguments.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to do this manually. I need to know how to pipe the output of directory listings to this command line program. (Of course, that directory listing should only contain *.mp3 files)

Comment: Please provide us with an example of the command line that you would issue to your mysterious merging routine, showing us the command you would use to combine three files into one, where every filename contains a space and every directoryname also contains a space. (Just EDIT it into your question)

Answer (score 2):

This will gather the filenames into one variable.

A variable can only have around 8100 characters in it so many files with long filenames will cause a problem.

```
@echo off
set var=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "*.mp3" /on /b /a-d ') do call set var=%%var%% "%%a"
set var
pause
```

Comment: So, no way to just pipe it like in Linux?

Comment: `"C:\Path to\mp3wrap" -a "C:\My Music\MyMP3.mp3" %1` put into a batch file then pipe to the batch with `dir /b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %A in ("c:\some folder\*.mp3") do "C:\Path to\mp3wrap" -a "C:\My Music\MyMP3.mp3" %A
```

You have to add one at a time.